# Panning, exact definition

Tags: user-interface, scroll, terminology, drag, panning

What is the difference between scrolling and panning?
Is panning identified as the action of dragging the image/background, while scrolling is only when you use scroll bars?

And, what is the difference between dragging and panning?

When I drag the map of google maps, which term is appropriate, dragging or panning???

Comment: Probably because it's not really on topic. Your question is about user interaction, which doesn't quite fall within the scope of SO.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Scrolling** typically involves scrollbars or a scroll-wheel on a mouse, but I have heard people refer to panning a map as scrolling as well (I would argue incorrectly).

**Panning** is exactly as you describe it - action of dragging the map (keeping it at the same scale, as opposed to **zooming**, which changes the scale level).

**Dragging = Panning** as you refer to them.

So what's the right word to use? Well, *Google (and others) use the term **pan/panning** in their mapping APIs* and **pan/panning** has widespread historical use in GIS terminology. So, technically-speaking, I would argue that **pan/panning** wins, but, generally-speaking, this is really just a difference in terminology.